# How to solve "Driver com.mysql.cj.jdbc.claims to not accept jdbcUrl" error?

Tags: spring-boot, heroku, exception, runtime, mysql-error-1064

I have Springboot application with MySQL as database. I am trying to host the application on Heroku. I am getting below error

I need help to resolve

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:postgresql://ec2-22-204-873-199.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d7gvjc8ejjul33?password=<ma
sked>&sslmode=require&user=kmawjakllmkaqa
```

Here is my application.properties file in SpringBoot

```
// Connect to heroku ClearDB MySql database
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${DBHOSTNAME}/${DBSCHEMA}?reconnect=true
spring.datasource.username=${DBUSERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${DBPASSWORD}
```

Comment: Any luck with this ?

Comment: Not yet .......